# Unable to see partial when using cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested, field, apache-cocoon

I have installed cocoon and added all of the necessary changes according to the examples outlined here: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/ERB-examples

Yet for some reason I am not able to see anything inside my partial.

views/order_items/_order_item_fields.html.erb:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :material %>
    TEST
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove order_item", f %>
</div>
```

views/orders/new.html.erb:

```
<div class="container text-center mt-4">
  <%= form_for @order do |f| %>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <h2>New Order</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="order_items">
      <%= f.fields_for :order_items do |order_item| %>
        <%= render "order_items/order_item_fields", f: order_item %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association "add order_item", f, :order_items %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Order.rb:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_many :order_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

I am also getting a Missing Template error:
`Missing partial orders/_order_item_fields, application/_order_item_fields with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.`

I believe if I'm trying to render the partial from another view folder, that adding the folder before the partial name should work: 
`<%= render "order_items/order_item_fields", f: order_item %>`

If I move `_order_item_fields.html.erb` from `views/order_items` into my `views/orders` directory, the page will render, but I still can't see anything inside the `order_item_fields` partial.

Comment: Are you building a field in your orders controller? ie `@order.order_items.build`

Comment: Please define "can't see anything inside the `order_item_fields` partial" because the partial contains just a label and a "TEST" message? But you do no see those either? Do you see the html change? Do you see an error in the javascript console in the browser (in other words: is the javascript working?).